# Cordova app crashes when the file access permission is denied

Tags: cordova, crash, getpicture

For a cordova/phonegap app, I am using ***cordova-plugin-camera*** to fetch  local files. and when invoking the ***navigator.camera.getPicture*** in android 6.0.1 devices a permission pop up appears asking permission to access files. On granting the permission its working. But when I deny the permission the app crashes. App gets closed and restarts automatically. Please help me to sort out the issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the provider section in my Manifest XML file.
You should add it inside the `<application></application>` tag

```
<provider
android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
android:authorities="ibas.provider"
android:exported="false"
android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
</provider>
```

Comment: It does not help, it still crashes. (Of course, i have changed the `authorities` and i have created `provider_paths` xml file).